# Android Studio Emulator error

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with android studio emulator. Every time I create my own activity, for example myscreen.xml, and in  MainActivity.java I change this line of code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) into setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);
```

the emulator shows me the following error: "UNFORTUNATELY LAUNCHER HAS STOPPED TO WORK". But if I use my main activity, for example  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, it works perfectly without an error.

I tried everything on Virtual Device: changing the ram size, VM heap, internal storage, SD card. Nothing works. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the layout of `myscreen.xml` is valid and it is contained within the `app/res/layout/*` folder the `myscreen.xml` layout should work.

If you would like further help, it would be useful to see both the `activity.java` in which the layout is being used and the `myscreen.xml` file.